# Is there some proper way to add model error for IEnumerable model field to highlight specific input in view but not all of them?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

Well I have some view model for, let's say, product:

```
public class ProductsAddModel 
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Names {get;set;}
}
```

I need to add several product names at a time but if there already exists product with one of the inputed names i want to add model error for `Names` and highlight the proper input in view. It basically looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(ProductsAddModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existedProducts = productRepository.AllProducts;
        if(model.Names.Any(n => existedProducts.Select(p => p.Name).Contains(n)))
        {
             ModelState.AddModelError("Names", "Error");
             return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case all `Names` inputs will be highlighted in view. How can I highlight specific name input - input which causes error. I have several solutions such ass past error Name with view data to view add add error class to text input if it's value matches error name. Something like:

```
var match = existedProducts.Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault(n => model.Names.Contains(n));
if(match != null)
{
      ModelState.AddModelError("Names", "Error");
      ViewBag.ErrorName = match.Name;
      return View(model);
}
```

And in view:

```
for (int i; i<Model.NumberOfInputs; i++)
{
    var value = Model.Names != null && Model.Names.Count() < index ? Model.Names.ToArray()[index] : string.Empty;
    var errorClass = value.Equals(ViewBag.ErrorName) ? "error" : string.Empty;
    <input type="text" name="Names" value="@value" class="@errorClass" />
}
```

... or create partial view for each input, save error name to temp data (not to view data to be able to sent this value through actions) with unique key, create render action for each input partial view, generate input id (or some custom data attribute) and temp data error key by the same pattern, check is there error for this input in temp data and add model error for "Names" if there is. Something like below:

```
var match = existedProducts.Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault(n => model.Names.Contains(n));
if(match != null)
{
      ModelState.AddModelError("Names", "Error");
      var key = string.Format("Names-{0}", match.Name);
      TempData[key] = "Error"; // or just true
      return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
for (int i; i<Model.NumberOfInputs; i++)
{
    var value = Model.Names != null && Model.Names.Count() < index ? Model.Names.ToArray()[index] : string.Empty;
    Html.RenderAction("RenderInputAction", new {name = value});
}
```

And additional action I was talking about:

```
public PartialViewResult RenderInputAction(string name)
{
     var key = string.Format("Names-{0}", name);
     if(TempData[key])
     {
          ModelState.AddModelError("Names", "Error");
     }
     return PartialView("NameInput", name);
}
```

and partial view itself:

```
<input type="text" name="Names" value="@Model" />
```

As you can see these are robust and strange approaches. I just want to know is there some proper and simpler way in MVC framework to handle such complex models and their model state errors? Maybe some prefix for name attribute to catch specific input or something like that. I'm just not even sure what to google to find the answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question! I wasn't sure.. so I tried it. Here's what I found.

My test had a model like this:

```
public class TestModel {
    public IList<string> Items { get; set; }

    public TestModel()
    {
        Items = new List<string>() { "Simon", "Whitehead" };
    }
}
```

..a View like this:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        <p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Items[i])
        </p>
        <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.Items[i])</p>
    }

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

This renders the names `Items[0]` and `Items[1]`. Basically, you add a model error with the same names:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Index_Post(TestModel model)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Items[i]))
        {
            // empty name is Items[i]
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Format("Items[{0}]", i), "Required");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Works fine for me. Individual boxes are required when blank. The result is:

[image: Required]

Comment: Well, thanks. After some manipulations I've got what I needed. But there another problem has appeared. When there were 5 text inputs with the same name and I posted, for example, two values - model contained two values. Now when I have 5 inputs with different names like `Name[i]` and post 2 values I get model with 5 values but 3 of them are `string.Empty`.  So I have to make additional select `.Names.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n))` which should be done somewhen during model binding. I try to make code as clean as possible. Thanks, it really helped me to avoid a lot of smelly code.